# Generating a list whose elements correspond to the counts of specific values of a different list as one traverses such list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let's imagine I have a list of zeros and ones: `example_list = {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}`.

I then create sub-lists of only zeros and only ones via the following commands:

```
zero_list = len[i for i in example_list if i == 0]
one_list = len[i for i in example_list if i == 1]
```

This gives `zero_list = {0, 0}` and `one_list = {1, 1, 1}`.

What I wish to do is to map the indices of the zeros and ones in `zero_list` and `one_list` respectively to a new list of the same length of `example_list`. I.e. I want to get:

```
new_list = {0, 0, 1, 1, 2}
```

Anyone have any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Can you provide an [mcve]? This question is currently to broad.

Comment: Sorry Christian, I am struggling to clarify further than in the description. Yes, I agree the question title is too broad, will edit.

Comment: Alright, thanks @T.Ray Jr., thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as counter-like dictionary while iterating over the list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
example_list = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
encountered = defaultdict(int)     # returns 0 as value for all keys that aren't set.

res = []
for item in example_list:
    res.append(encountered[item])  # append the number of times this number was seen
    encountered[item] += 1         # increment the times

>>> res
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
```

Or if you would like it as generator function:

```
def cumulative_count(it):
    cnts = defaultdict(int)
    for item in it:
        yield cnts[item]
        cnts[item] += 1

>>> list(cumulative_count([0, 1, 0, 1, 1]))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
```